# How to remove some data but not all from mysql-table

Tags: php, mysql

How can I with PHP remove some data but not all from my mysql-table?

For example, I have the table "People" which looks like this:

```
________________________________
1 | John Doe  | Close Friend   |
2 | Jenna Doe | Distant Friend |
```

If I would then like to remove for example the last names, Doe, how can I do that? I can't use Update to just John and Jenna, since the column containing the names might consist of more info than just the first and last name. If it also consists of for example middlenames I wouldn't want to erase that.

Comment: your question is not undersand can u please explain clearly

Comment: Kindly have a look at the Mysql documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `UPDATE mytable
SET name = REPLACE(name, ' Doe', '')`

Answer (score 0):

To remove substring `'Doe'` you can use [**`REPLACE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET name = REPLACE(name, 'Doe', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column name is `name` use this query

```
UPDATE `People` SET name=TRIM(REPLACE(name, 'Doe', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only names which are ending on 'Doe', try this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET name = SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(name) - 3)
WHERE RIGHT(name, 3) = 'Doe'
```

This query will not replace 'Doe' if it is presented in the middle of string. Only rows with 'Doe' on the end will be affected.